# Hibernate is throwing me "FROM unexpected" and Unchecked Assignment on IDE

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate and with the help of online tutorial I was able to utilize hibernate but I am getting an error while reading. Can you please help? Basically the issue is, my IntelliJ IDE says 'FROM' unexpected on the quert and Unchecked Assignment warning on the below mentioned line.

[Error ScreenShot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5SeAyRbFySrcmFYdkVYY01odzg)

```
//Imports
import com.kiran.Model.Entity.User;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import java.util.List;

public void readUsers() {
    Session session = generateSession();
    try {
        // start a transaction
        session.beginTransaction();
   // Errors on below line: Unchecked Assignment java.util.list and 'FROM' unexpected
        List<User> users = session.createQuery(
                "FROM User")
                .getResultList(); 
        displayUsers(users);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    }
    finally {
        factory.close();
    }
}



private  Session generateSession() {
    factory = new Configuration()
            .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
            .addAnnotatedClass(User.class)
            .buildSessionFactory();
    return factory.getCurrentSession();
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `User` class defined? If so you can try to specify the path of that class in query like `"From com.example.entity.User"`

Comment: Yes I have. and I have imported it: import com.kiran.Model.Entity.User;

Comment: I think it should be `List<User> users = session.createQuery(
                "FROM User")
                .list();`

Comment: I tried that, doesn't work.

Comment: Can you paste your User class, and hibernate.cfg.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

`List<User> users = session.createQuery(
                "FROM User").list();`

Answer (score 0):

try creating your query as

```
select u from User u
```

and see what happens.

Turning on showsql in the Hibernate config can help tracking down problems with your JPQL, HQL, and SQL.

Comment: Looks like its just the warning/error on the IDE. When I run the program, works without any issue.  Something weird.

Comment: the screenshot you added shows a warning, yes. Which indicates it doesn't know enough about your data model to validate the query correctly.

Comment: @KiranGautam is right. Intellij showed as an issue but i ran the program and works without any issue.